# If else statement with mysql table? - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I need to make an if else statement that will prevent a user from bidding on an item if they are the highest bidder. I think it would go a little something like this.

```
if ($accountid = the accountid in the bidhistory table)
{
    echo "You are the highest bidder!";

}
else
{
$sql="INSERT INTO bidhistory (accountid, biditemid)
VALUES ($accountid, $itemid)"; 

mysql_query("
UPDATE bidhistory
SET bidprice = bidprice + 1
WHERE biditemid = " .
@mysql_escape_string($itemid));

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in adding bid for item: ".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

I'm not sure how to reference the accountid from the bidhistory table. Also, if there is a better way to do this, please point me in the wright direction. Thanks!

Comment: In your `bidhistory` table, does it have a primary key? Like `bidhistory_id`? So it will be unique.

Comment: @LoganWayne Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Note:

- You can fetch the row of the highest bid with the specific item first.
  Then check if the highest bidder (`accountid`) is the same with the current user.
- You can check the notes I had for some lines quoted in `/* ... */`

Your query for checking:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT accountid FROM bidhistory WHERE biditem = '$itemid' ORDER BY bidhistoryid DESC LIMIT 1"); /* GET THE LAST ROW FOR WHO BIDS LAST; AND REPLACE NECESSARY COLUMN NAME (unique/primary) - bidhistoryid */
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $checkaccountid = $row['accountid']; /* STORE THE USER THAT BIDS LAST FOR THIS ITEM */
}

if($checkaccountid == $accountid){ /* THEN COMPARE IT WITH THE CURRENT USER */
  /* CODE YOU WANT TO DO IF HE/SHE IS THE LAST BIDDER ALREADY */
}
else {
  /* IF NOT, HE/SHE CAN STILL BID */
}
```

But I recommend that you use `mysqli_*` rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API.

```
$con = new mysqli("YourHost", "Username", "Password", "Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT accountid FROM bidhistory WHERE biditem = ? ORDER BY bidhistoryid DESC LIMIT 1")){  
  $stmt->bind_param("i",$itemid); /* BIND THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY ABOVE */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_result($checkaccountid); /* STORE THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
  $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */

  if($checkaccountid == $accountid){
    /* CODE YOU WANT TO DO IF HE/SHE IS THE LAST BIDDER ALREADY */
  }
  else {
    /* IF NOT, HE/SHE CAN STILL BID */
  }
  $stmt->close();

} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that says $checkaccountid is undefined.

Comment: @LuluSparks - Did you change the query with the corresponding column name (`bidhistoryid`)? Or try running this query to your server side `SELECT accountid FROM bidhistory WHERE biditem = 1 ORDER BY bidhistoryid DESC` or with any valid `biditem` number. And what did you use? My first set of code, or the second one?

Comment: I used the first set. And what do you mean by did I change the query?

Comment: @LuluSparks - I mean the `bidhistoryid`. What is your unique/primary key id for your `bidhistory` table?

Comment: @LuluSparks - try running this query `SELECT accountid FROM bidhistory WHERE biditem = 1 ORDER BY bidhistoryid DESC` in your server side (in your PhpMyAdmin page). And lets see if there is a result.

Comment: @LuluSparks - Sorry, I just got back. Good to know you've made it work.

Comment: I actually got this to work just once. Every time after that, I've gotten an error.